Linux terminal redirect output of piped commands to terminal and file
While this topic seems a duplication of queries such as How to redirect output to a file and stdout, I cannot make my command sequence to produce the desired result.
This is the command sequence that works:
mosquitto_sub -h 192.168.1.5 -v -t ArgyleCourt/Property/# | xargs -d$'\n' -L1 sh -c 'date "+%Y-%m-%d %T.%3N $0"' | grep "IrrigationTank\|BoreP\|Hub"

... and produces the desired result:

2024-12-25 10:54:17.255 ArgyleCourt/Property/IrrigationTank/WaterLevel 84
2024-12-25 10:55:17.254 ArgyleCourt/Property/IrrigationTank/WaterLevel 83
2024-12-25 10:55:35.243 ArgyleCourt/Property/BorePump/HeartBeat ON
2024-12-25 10:55:35.308 ArgyleCourt/Property/Hub/HeartBeat ON
2024-12-25 10:56:17.253 ArgyleCourt/Property/IrrigationTank/WaterLevel 84
2024-12-25 10:56:33.479 ArgyleCourt/Property/Hub/Notification Arduino_TheHub|INFO|DHCP OK
2024-12-25 10:57:17.251 ArgyleCourt/Property/IrrigationTank/WaterLevel 84
2024-12-25 10:57:35.234 ArgyleCourt/Property/BorePump/HeartBeat ON
2024-12-25 10:57:35.295 ArgyleCourt/Property/Hub/HeartBeat ON
2024-12-25 10:57:52.391 ArgyleCourt/Property/Hub/ChipTemp 45

This command line uses a mosquitto (MQTT broker) command to query the broker for the specific topic ArgyleCourt/Property/#, piped to args to add a date/time stamp and piped to grep to filter out the messages for three controllers (TheHub, IrrigationTank and BorePump).
According to the linked query above, this:
(mosquitto_sub -h 192.168.1.5 -v -t ArgyleCourt/Property/# | xargs -d$'\n' -L1 sh -c 'date "+%Y-%m-%d %T.%3N $0"' | grep "IrrigationTank\|BoreP\|Hub") 2>&1 | tee MQTT_TankfillMsgs.txt

... it should have the output in the terminal and the file. The file is created, but never written to. The () are used to capture/group the whole command sequence.
Another response suggested to use unbuffer. I added this command before mosquitto_sub, but it made no difference to the outcome.
What am I missing?

Try simplifying the command until you find where it fails.  For example, does (echo hi) 2>&1) | tee MQTT_TankfillMsgs.txt work.

@ash, well, your example creates an error due to two closing brackets :) But, I have taken out the grep part and then it works (though unfiltered). I am still puzzled why it doesn't work with the grep part.

There's not much point in adding unbuffer to the left side of a pipe only; the right side will still buffer. Add this to all commands (including tee as well), does this make a difference?

Does the pipeline mosquitto_sub | xargs | grep complete? Do you see its output appear in the terminal?

@egmont, yes, pipeline completes (as shown in OP). unbuffer before all commands, makes no difference.

I tried variations of the pipeline; these do work, but, when adding grep neither terminal nor file outputs.

"when adding grep neither terminal nor file outputs" -- well, then it sounds that nothing is wrong with the pipeline or buffering or tee, don't you simply give grep a pattern that does not match any of its lines?

@egmont; pls see OP; the pattern is valid and showing a result. I have even removed the OR in the pattern to rule it out being the culprit. I also monitor the the non-tee-ed output in another terminal at the same time.

Is there any chance you could please come up with a reproducible example? E.g. if you record the output of mosquitto_sub | xargs in a file, and replace that by cat'ing that file, does that trigger the same unexpected behavior? If so, you could attach that file and we could repeat the exact same steps.

Have done this, and it works with cat recorded_messages.txt | grep 'IrrigationTank\|BoreP\|Hub' | tee MQTT_TankfillMsgs.txt. However, I can't seem to post the recorded_messages; which are the same as in the OP (cut and paste from there?!).

I eventually figured it out:
mosquitto_sub -h 192.168.1.5 -v -t ArgyleCourt/Property/# | xargs -d$'\n' -L1 sh -c 'date "+%Y-%m-%d %T.%3N $0"' | grep --line-buffered "IrrigationTank\|BoreP\|Hub" | tee MQTT_TankfillMsgs.txt

... adding -line-buffered to the grep command will output the filtered MQTT input to both, file and terminal.
Thanks for hanging in there.

If that's the case, your original command would have written output too if you'd waited longer (for the quantity of output to be enough for the buffer to fill).
